# What's the best way to wrap an ES6 library?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, umd

What's the best way to setup an ES6 library so that it's modular and transpiles into **one ES5 UMD file**? I looked at the way async.js and lodash do it, but it's hard to understand what's going on.

For example, `index.js`:

```
import doSomething from './doSomething';

class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Example';
  }
}

Object.assign(Example.prototype, {
  doSomething
});

export default Example;
```

and `doSomething.js`:

```
export default function doSomething() {
  return this.name;
}
```

So that user can do something like this:

```
var example = new Example();
example.doSomething(); // Example
```

I'm having no luck with Babel, as `transform-es2015-modules-umd` is not evaluating paths correctly, and Babel's not bundling it all into one ES5 file either. Anyone have a simple example for something like this?

Comment: to create a bundle you can use an additional tool like webpack, browserify or the awesome https://github.com/rollup/rollup

Comment: What you're looking for is called "module bundler". There are a few out there.

Comment: Boh. So easy with rollup, I feel silly now :) Thank you all.